# Marvin Project plugins for webcam: No image is loaded from webcam

Tags: java, video, project, webcam, marvin-framework

I'm trying to run the example provided at the MarvinProject website:

http://marvinproject.sourceforge.net/en/examples/videoFilters.html

that one, but I can't make it work, I'm using an HP pavilion dv7 laptop.
I already installed the javacv libraries.

My questions are: why am I getting this exception? why can't I see anything in my frame window?

Thanks very much in advance!

```
--------------------Configuration: <Default>--------------------
Exception in thread "Thread-3" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
    at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:553)
at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:532)
    at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core$CvArr.<clinit>(opencv_core.java:156)
    at     com.googlecode.javacv.VideoInputFrameGrabber.grab(VideoInputFrameGrabber.java:163)
    at marvin.video.MarvinJavaCVAdapter.getFrame(MarvinJavaCVAdapter.java:115)
    at Uncanny.marvinVideo.run(marvinVideo.java:203)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't overwrite cause
    at java.lang.Throwable.initCause(Throwable.java:456)
    at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:581)
at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:532)
    at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.<clinit>(opencv_core.java:134)
    ... 9 more
```

edit: I forgot to include this... The exception is thrown at this line of code: imageIn = videoInterface.getFrame(); it's inside the run() method. Thanks!

**EDIT 2:** I just figured out what was the problem!

I just needed to load a couple more libraries! the CPP ones!

https://code.google.com/p/javacv/downloads/detail?name=javacv-0.6-cppjars.zip

those! Thanks everyone anyways! Cheers.

P.D.: I still can't answer my own question due to being a newbie and not having enough reputation, that's why I'm editing, I have to wait 7 hours or so, I will be posting this as an answer soon! Cheers!

Comment: I'M SORRY! I forgot to include this...

The exception is thrown at this line of code:

imageIn = videoInterface.getFrame(); 

it's inside the run() method. Thanks!

Comment: If you have an edit to do, write it in the question, not as a comment.

Comment: Sorry again!, I was looking for the edit button to do it but couldn't find it! I just realized where it is now! I'm a noob here, apologies. thanks.

Comment: Don't worry, it was just a suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figured out what was the problem!

I just needed to load a couple more libraries! the CPP ones!

https://code.google.com/p/javacv/downloads/detail?name=javacv-0.6-cppjars.zip

those! Thanks everyone anyways! Cheers.